Prove that points are non-coplanar
Planes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are different if and only if there exist points $A$, $B$ on $\alpha$ and points $C$, $D$ on $\beta$ such that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are non-coplanar.
I proved the opposite direction by assuming the contrary, i.e., we claim that $\alpha = \beta$. Then, since $A$, $B$ are on $\alpha$ and $B$, $C$ are also on $\alpha$ because of $\alpha = \beta$. We have that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are on $\alpha$, so they are coplanar, which is a contradiction.
How do I prove first direction of this statement using only axioms of incidence? I tried using the contrapositive: Let $A$, $B$ be on $\alpha$ and $C$, $D$ be on $\beta$ such that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are coplanar. We claim that $\alpha$ is equal to $\beta$. But I am stuck.
Can someone please help me with this?

Certainly, $A, B, C$ are on a plane.  Is $D$ also on that plane?

The negation of "there exist points A, B on  and points C, D on  such that A,B,C,D are non-coplanar" is "for all points A, B on  and C, D on ,  A,B,C,D are coplanar"
